# Who is Cersei's first actual kill (or kills)?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the season 6 finale of Game of Thrones,

> Cersei uses wildfire to destroy the Sept of Baelor and kill many people, including the High Sparrow, the Tyrells, as well as Kevan and Lancel Lannister. But was this her first time killing?

Throughout the series, Cersei has often been wrongly blamed for various murders:

> * It was assumed that she had killed John Arryn, but that ended up being Littlefinger and Lysa Arryn
>  * She was initially blamed for killing Robert's bastards, but that turned out to be Joffrey's doing
>  * She had never intended for Ned to be killed, only for him to be sent to the wall
>  * Jaimie is the one who pushes Bran out the window, not Cersei
>
>  She contributes to Robert's death by feeding him strong-wine, but it could certainly be argued that his stupidity and over-indulgence lead to his death.

#### Before the Green Trial, does Cersei ever kill anyone?

Comment: [Melara Hetherspoon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Melara_Hetherspoon).

Comment: She's "had" many people killed, so she's at least responsible for the deaths of many people.

Comment: About Robert's death, she specifically says in one episode that she arranged the death of her husband, so I would assume it counts as much as ordering someone to burn some building with people in it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The following is true of the book series, but not confirmed to be also true in the TV series:

> When Cersei was young she visited a local woods witch named Maggy the Frog, who gave her the infamous prophecy about her marrying a king and losing her children (which has appeared in the TV show). Accompanying her was a girl named Melara Heatherspoon, who was the only witness to that prophecy apart from Cersei herself and Maggy. Fearful of the prophecy and what would happen if it became known, Cersei then murdered Melara by pushing her into an open well, drowning her. (A Feast for Crows, Chapter 12, Cersei III)

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware of this! And this is (almost) certainly her first kill.

Comment: @jmite - It is also the only (as far as we know) murder that she directly committed as opposed to having arranged.

Comment: Also, Littlefinger assures:

`I've also heard whispers that Robert got a pair of twins on a serving wench at Casterly Rock, three years ago when he went west for Lord Tywin's tourney. Cersei had the babes killed, and sold the mother to a passing slaver. Too much an affront to Lannister pride, that close to home.`

It is worth noting that Littlefinger rarely tells thruths.

Answer (score 15):

Cersei Lannister **took part in the death of Robert Baratheon**. Aside from the other references in the show and books, she **specifically "confesses" this to Septa Unella during the wineboarding scene**. There's no thought of argument otherwise. Arguably, all of Ned's men in the throne room can be tied to her, since she bought Janos Slynt to have him doublecross Ned.

I don't know if you want to count where she was circumstantially stopped from being responsible for the deaths of many people along the way, depends if you're more concerned about fact or intent I guess:

- She orders Ilyn Payne to be at the Red Keep during the siege to spare all the ladies from rape (by killing them first).
- She was ready to poison Tommen to prevent his capture by Stannis Baratheon.
- She wanted Tyrion dead, and sought to push that when provided with an opportunity; although you could argue that was "justified" if she genuinely believed him responsible, it is heavily alluded to that she has wanted Tyrion dead for years.
- If you count direwolves, she pushes for Lady's death in retribution for an incident Lady was never involved in.

In the books, there are other characters that she effectively gets rid of or orders gotten rid off along the way, and other plots. The second High Septon (on the basis that he was appointed by Tyrion) was Kettleblacked, her maid Senelle was given to Qyburn for spying on her, Falyse Stokeworth was given to Qyburn after the Stokeworths failed to contain/kill Bronn, etc. None of these characters are part of the show, however. She publicly forbids Robert from being in the melee at the Hand's Tourney knowing that will convince him to do so (and so have him "accidentally" killed). She sends Balon Swann to Dorne with orders to assassinate Prince Trystane and blame it on Tyrion.